# How-to provide a status message prior to invoking a custom controller method

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable, commandbutton

I have a custom controller to obtain a record set, which I invoke from a commandbutton. pbtable is a pageblocktable populated by the method searchproperties shown below.

```
 <apex:commandButton action="{!SearchProperties}" value="Search for Matching Properties" reRender="pbtable" />
```

Because it can take a bit of server time before returning a result set, I want to provide a message indicating the search has begun. Everything is nestled in pageblock and sections. Currently, I provide a message on the pageblocksection indicating both the length of time it took to produce the result set and how many records were found. So, ideally, upon clicking the commandbutton, I want to update the title to inform users the search has begun. Any ideas or different approaches are most appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
 <apex:pageblocksection Columns="1" title="Step 3 - Select a property   {!ShowTotalMatches}" id="pbtable" />
```

Comment: You can use the status attribute on the commandButton for this, in conjunction with the apex:actionStatus element: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionStatus.htm?search_text=actionStatus

Comment: @rael_kid You should add this as an answer.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check it out right now and let you know how I make out.

Comment: Been playing around with it, and while I made progress, this is nothing more than a timer, which doesn't even fire off until at minimum 5 seconds later. Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  for providing message.

```
  <apex:commandButton action="{!SearchProperties}" value="Search for Matching Properties" reRender="pbtable" status="myStatus">

  <apex:actionStatus  id="myStatus" startText=" Loading..." stopText=""/>

  <apex:pageblocksection Columns="1" title="Step 3 - Select a property   {!ShowTotalMatches}" id="pbtable" >
```

Reference
[Simple action status in Salesforce](http://www.infallibletechie.com/2014/03/simple-action-status-in-salesforce.html)

[apex:actionStatus](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionStatus.htm)

Comment: Fantastic! That's great and works well, but can I update the header in that pageblocksection? There's no status attribute available for a PBS so while I can output a status message, it won't be visible on the PBS header where I'd like it.

Comment: if you want your  PageBlockSection title to be dynamic , Then you have to create <apex:outputPanel > , give the id of the present pageblocksection to outputPanle. keep the pageblocksection inside outpupanel and render the outputPanel.   something like this ,  <apex:outputPanel id="pbtable" >   <apex:pageblocksection Columns="1" title="{! dynamicTitleForEachRender }"  > //your content   </apex:pageBlockSection>   </apex:outputPanel>

Answer (score 0):

I usually have something like this on all my pages:

```
<apex:actionStatus id="loading" onstart="startLoading();" onstop="stopLoading();" />
    <div class="customLoader" id="customLoaderDiv"> 
        <div class="customLoaderContainer">
            <apex:image styleClass="loadingIcon" url="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bundle, 'img/loader.gif')}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</apex:actionStatus>
```

Along with these javascript functions:

```
$j(function() {
    $j('.customLoader').hide();
}

loadingCounter = 0;
function startLoading(){
    loadingCounter++; 
    $j('.customLoader').show(); 
}

function stopLoading(){
    if(--loadingCounter <= 0){ 
        $j('.customLoader').hide();
    }
}
```

If you add the `status="loading"` attribute on an `apex:commandButton` or `apex:actionSupport` or whatever supports it the function `startLoading();` will be called and the loader will be shown. When the function completes `stopLoading();` is called and the loader will be hidden. Usually I also add functionality to disable and re-enable buttons in the functions, but you could do whatever you need. This

Comment: I like this, however it appears on the initial page load showing the action status, yet with the first and subsequent clicks, it works perfectly. How do you initialize it?

Comment: Ah, yes, there's a tiny piece of Javascript for that. I've added it to my answer.